# How to make the Identity Login Page the startup page in dotnetcore 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am creating a dotnetcore 2.1 application and have scaffolded the Identity Login page. However, I don't know how to make the login page the startup page.
I know how to do it with Controllers and Actions but not with the scaffolded page.
Please could someone enlighten me on how to do this ?

Comment: If you just add the `Authorize` attribute to all controllers, then by default, any unauthenticated users will be automatically redirected to your login page.

Answer (score 0):

As Brendan Green wrote in the comments you can add a restriction in your startup.cs file.

This works in Asp.Net Core 2.0 and 2.1.

You can do this by use the following code in your startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(o =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
}
```

If you want to do this you need a user-store. So you have to use the template with individual user accounts or you do with "new Scaffolded item" -> "identity"

I hope this help you?

Comment: Thanks Darem,  but that didn't work.
I am actually creating an application in aspnetcore 2.1 and to my surprise I didn't see an Account Controller and Account View scaffolded by the template. I had to right-click on the project -> Add -> New Scaffolded Item -> Select Identity -> and then select the all or the specific Identity pages to be scaffolded.
After doing that I get the scaffolded code generated in Areas ->Pages -> Account.
What I also notice is that the generated .cshtml file has an associate code-behind file with methods OnGetAsync and OnPostAsync.How to make Login the startpage?

Comment: @wiseguytamo when you do the second approch to add the the service in the startup.cs file it works also in Asp.Net Core 2.1, so i think that the way you have to go i update my anwser